# Is it possible to use AutoHotKey with Ansible?

Tags: windows, ansible, autohotkey

I'm currently using Ansible to install different services on a Windows Machine but I need to edit some parameters in a properties window. I've tried using the following code to run my AHK script, called CCM, but it doesn't work as intended (doesn't change any parameters).

```
  - name: Run CCM script to configure server
    win_psexec:
      command: 'C:\temp\CCM.exe'
      interactive: yes
      system: yes
```

I was wondering if it even is possible to use AHK with Ansible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible to run AutoHotKey from within Ansible, although this should only be done when no other scripting option is possible

AHK has to be run in a console GUI session so it can interact with the windows desktop. That can be done with an extension program called psexec, which is part of the Windows Sysinternals Utilities package. You can download this for free from Microsoft.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/

First find the session ID:

```
for /f "tokens=3" %i in ('qwinsta console ^| find "console"') do set GUI_SESSION_ID=%i
```

Then use psexec to launch a GUI console session and then run AutoHotkey in this:

```
psexec -i %GUI_SESSION_ID% autohotkey myscript.ahk
```

You can then run an AHK script like usual.